# Trying to get an arraylist from an activity to a customview

Tags: android, arraylist, view

I would like to know how I could pass an ArrayList of Float from an activity to an CustomView, I made a lot of research but I didn't find anything that could really help me out and sometimes what looked like that would work out would be if I could use an intent in the Custom View side but everytime I tried to call the function getIntent() I got a message saying that this function was not defined in my CustomView, I tried to use the object Bundle but I got lost, this array is passed from the MainActivity to the CustomView but the MainActivity will still be processing data in this ArrayList so the CustomView has to be able to access the data that was processed in the MainActivity as the time pass by my intention is to use this data and draw a graph line with canvas. My CustomView is initialized inside of the activity_main.xml.I have all the idea how to finish this application but this step is freaking me out. I will appreciate all and any help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your ArrayList via constructor or create a setter in your component and update list update list after changes in MainActivity.

Comment: my CustomView is embeded in the MainActivity xml file is it possible to get the array by constructor anyway? And the updates made on the array from the MainActivity occur every second. I am gonna take a look at both options anyway. Cheers

Comment: Do you want to display firstly static array or dynamic array. Can you store your array in strings.xml or arrays.xml, as example?

Comment: Lads I found the solution it is really simple when the View is embedded in the xml file what you want to do is to create a function in the view which gets the array then you pull your view through the mainactivity and call this function passing the array.